# how to customize the dataset on a primeng bar graph

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using primeng on an angular and I want to create a bar graph where the last 2 horizontal bars are colored differently.

At the moment the last 2 are being wrapped around and interpreted as dogs and cats
My question is, how would I edit the graph so that the two orange bars on dog and cat are on tiger and lion?

For some reason StackOverflow is not letting me post a picture so here is the link to an image hosting site I uploaded the example to:
https://ibb.co/jZyxddC

component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-status-logs-graph',
  templateUrl: './status-logs-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./status-logs-graph.component.scss']
})
export class StatusLogsGraphComponent implements OnInit {

  basicData: any;
  basicOptions: any;

  constructor() { 
      this.basicData = {
    labels: ['dog', 'cat', 'hamster', 'lizard', 'tiger', 'lion'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Domestic Animals',
            backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
            data: [ 32, 54, 21, 11]
        },
        {
            label: 'Wild Animals',
            backgroundColor: '#FFA726',
            data: [28, 48]
        }
    ]
};
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {

}
}
```

Comment: What is the question? « At the moment the last 2 are being wrapped around and interpreted as dogs and cats » is not a question. From your code that looks very logical since cats and dogs are the first two in the animal array. Your code seems to work fine. What’s the expected output? Can you do ‘data: [0,0,0,0,28, 48]’?

Comment: @Klaassiek I have updated my post to reflect your feedback. Using data: [0,0,0,0,28, 48] would not work because the extra zeros add spacing to the graph and the label '0' next to all the domestic animals. My expected output is two orange bars on the "tiger" and "lion". while the remaining animals have only blue bars.

Answer (score 2):

Primeng uses chartjs under the hood. You can find its documentation [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

With chartjs you can define the color of each bar of your chart individually. If you put all the animals in the same dataset and then define the colors for each of the animals, you come close to what you want to achieve. The only downside is that you should hide the legend, since it will just say "Domestic animals", since you are only using one dataset. (You can of course create your own legend using html/css.) Here is a full example:

```js
var basicData = {
    labels: ['dog', 'cat', 'hamster', 'lizard', 'tiger', 'lion'],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [ 32, 54, 21, 11, 28, 48],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#42A5F5',
                '#42A5F5',
                '#42A5F5',
                '#42A5F5',
                '#FFA726',
                '#FFA726'
            ]
        }
    ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: basicData,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.4.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Now, this is not very scalable. A better approach might be to put all data in an array and combine the dataset on the fly. This way, you can always easily add an animal. See this example:

```js
var animals = [
    {
        name: 'dog',
        data: 32,
        type: 'domestic'
    },
    {
        name: 'cat',
        data: 54,
        type: 'domestic'
    },
    {
        name: 'hamster',
        data: 21,
        type: 'domestic'
    },
    {
        name: 'lizard',
        data: 11,
        type: 'domestic'
    },
    {
        name: 'tiger',
        data: 28,
        type: 'wild'
    },
    {
        name: 'lion',
        data: 48,
        type: 'wild'
    }
];
var labels = [];
var data = [];
var colors = [];
for(var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++){
    labels.push(animals[i].name);
    data.push(animals[i].data);
    if(animals[i].type === 'domestic'){
        colors.push('#42A5F5');
    }
    else{
        colors.push('#FFA726');
    }
}
var basicData = {
    labels:labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: colors
        }
    ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: basicData,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.4.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Chart.js [`skipNull`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#general) property, and set it equal to `true`.

(PrimeNG's charts all extend/use Chart.js).

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean do you want to horizontal separate bar charts for domestic animal and wild animals and domestic animal should be different colors?

In that case you can use Ngx-charts. You can get an idea using below link

https://swathisprasad.medium.com/building-data-visualization-with-angular-and-ngx-charts-375942d49fd6